# DFT+U Values from Reference Formation Energies

Tags: transition-metals, dft-u

I would like to calculate some DFT+U values for a few elements (Fe, Co, Ni, Cu, Zn?) and am attempting to take the approach from the [Ceder 2006](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.73.195107) paper.  Where does the Ceder paper take its experimental values from?  It seems to be from NIST and a "Materials Thermochemistry" book, but I am having trouble finding or accessing these.

Is there a list compiled for the redox reactions in the Ceder paper?  I could of course, just read the plot, but I would prefer a primary source for this data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't help with the textbook, but the NIST-JANAF Thermochemical Tables are available here:

https://janaf.nist.gov/

Comment: Ah, somehow I missed the exact citation.  I saw it was NIST but missed the JANAF part and got confused thinking I was unable to access something.  Thanks

Comment: +1 for the quick answer! It will help this become a Hot Network Question. It might not be where the Ceder 2006 paper got it's experimental values from, but there's plenty of other places to get experimental values. For example, @TristanMaxson would the Active Thermochemical Tables be of any use: https://atct.anl.gov/ ?